# How to efficiently insert an element in an arbitrary position of an array?

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, insert, time-complexity

Are there any data structure or algorithm to insert an element in an arbitrary position of an array efficiently like in *O(1)* or *O(log(n))* complexity? In *C++* there is a linked list data structure which can efficiently insert an element at an `iterator` position in *O(1)* complexity, but to get the `iterator` to that position it take *O(n)* which is very costly. So are there any data structure could support this function `void insert(int pos, int val)` which insert an element `val` before the position `pos` and the complexity of this function is small?

Comment: Small in respect of what? What are you trying to achieve? You choose a data structure as a tool to solve a problem.

Comment: A tree could do it, but I don't see anything in STL for that.

Comment: A linked list has O(1) insertion, but finding the insertion point tends to dominate the O(n) insertion in an array. Computers these days are really fast in shifting stuff around as long as it's contiguous in memory. Arrays (as implemented by `std::vector`) are the fastest choice most of the time.

Comment: If `array` is a strict requirement I think you are out of luck here. There is no way to insert an element in a position `i` in less that O(n) (keeping the rest of the elements).Is another story If you are looking for other data structure that supports insertion and lookup with better complexity than O(n). What do you also mean by "right before"? Does this mean data has to lie in contiguous memory?

Comment: No, I only need the elements to be in the correct order like in an array.

Comment: @KienPham I think a `set` or a `multiset` is what you are looking for in this context.

Comment: What about other operations complexities? Indexing in `O(logn)` would be ok?

Comment: @KienPham Do you need the indexes to be sorted contiguous integer ? If so, I think that whatever you do, an insertion would require to update the index of every element after the inserted element, which sounds like an O(n) operation to me. Can you give more detail about your constraints?

Comment: @Michel `n` might be as large as 100000 or 1000000.

Comment: I think it will be helpful if you also write down other operation you need for the data structure (e.g. query). If you only do insertion, you probably don't need that data structure.

Comment: If you want a logical array, i.e. each index is mapped to the element appearing at that index, it's logically impossible to have both O(1) insertion and O(1) lookup per index, since you need to update O(n) indices per insertion. If you simply want an ordered data structure, `set` or `map` would be the way to go (which is O(log n) per query). We need more details to answer this.

Comment: How large can `n` be?

Comment: A [skip list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list) will give you amortized O(log n) insertion, deletion, and find by key. An indexed skip list (also in that article) will give you O(log n) access by index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some data structures that support fast 'insert to position' operation.

1. [**Rope**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rope_(data_structure)) or similar self-balanced tree data structures.

   [image]

   **Under the hood**: a self-balanced tree with each node containing the 'size' of its subtree.

   **Insert complexity**: `O(logn)`.

   **C++ implementation**: [SGI STL](https://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Rope.html) has a rope implementation as an extension.
2. [**Skip list**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list) or modifications.

   [image]

   **Under the hood**: `O(logn)` linked lists with nodes referring to elements of underlying list, allowing to skip elements in the lists below

   **Insert complexity**: `O(logn)`.

   **C++ implementation**: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/116345/skip-list-implementation
3. **[SQRT decomposition](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sqrt-square-root-decomposition-technique-set-1-introduction/)** technique linked list-based data structure (I don't know if it has a name).

   [image]

   **Under the hood**: Doubly linked list with index array. Index array has `O(sqrt(n))` elements referring to the elements of the list, allowing to skip `O(sqrt(n))` elements at a time.

   **Insert complexity**: `O(sqrt(n))`.